# Order of local and global truncation error in a finite volume scheme

Tags: numerical-analysis, fluid-dynamics, finite-volume

Can the order of the local truncation error be higher than the order of global truncation error in a finite volume method?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "Local". Do you mean how you reconstruct your interface / trace values?